# IRC (or weechat in particular): how to prevent accidental text input

Tags: irc, irssi, weechat

So a couple of times my current IRC channel has had terminal commands (e.g. ls) accidentally entered, resulting in a few comments. Is there a way, either in IRC clients in general, or my current client weechat to prevent text input, ideally as a toggle so I can turn it off and on?

I've found this script [input_lock.rb](http://www.weechat.org/scripts/source/input_lock.rb.html/) which apparently allows this feature, but either it doesn't work or I didn't spend long enough trying. Has anyone more experience?